# How do I rename a mongo collection in Mongoid?

Tags: mongoid, mongoid3

I have a collection called artists, i'd like to rename it to artist_lookups.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Mongoid Docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html):

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection: "artists", database: "music", session: "secondary"
end
```

Use `store_in collection: "artist_lookups"` in your model. This will let you store your `Artist` model in the `artist_lookups` collection.

If you want to preserve the existing data in the `artists` collection, and rename it, I suggest shutting down your app temporarily, renaming the collection to `artist_lookups` on your MongoDB server, and then restarting the app.

Comment: I can't keep the model name, because of a collision with another Artist model so I took the latter approach.

Answer (score 6):

With mongoid5 / mongo ruby driver 2:

```
# if you need to check whether foo exists
return unless Mongoid.default_client.collections.map(&:name).include?('foo')

# rename to bar
Mongoid.default_client.use(:admin).command(
  renameCollection: "#{Mongoid.default_client.database.name}.foo",
  to: "#{Mongoid.default_client.database.name}.bar"
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Very simple, in mongo shell, do that:

> db.artists.renameCollection( "artist_lookups" );

if you want to drop artist_lookups if it exist:

> db.artists.renameCollection( "artist_lookups", true );

Some exception you can got.

- 10026 – Raised if the source namespace does not exist.
- 10027 – Raised if the target namespace exists and dropTarget is either false or unspecified.
- 15967 – Raised if the target namespace is an invalid collection name.

Answer (score 2):

```
db.artists.renameCollection("artist_lookups")
```

will work for sure.